# How to get CCK optionsfield value, if I have the key for that value?

Tags: entities

I have a CCK select list where I defined key|value pairs.

When I execute a node_load for that node, I only get the key (in my case an integer) stored in Drupal.

How can I get the value of that key easily? Is there a Drupal function?

something like, cck_value('field_name',$key) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Node_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load/6) will return fully-populated node object.

Value of cck fields in node object are usualy accessed in this way:

```
 $my_node_object = node_load($nid);
 $myVar = $my_node_object->field_your_field_name['0']['value']
```

You can see what $node object contain if you do

```
dsm($my_node_object); // Devel module must be turned on
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found this meanwhile
http://www.mugginsoft.com/content/getting-allowed-values-cck-field